# Does Windows 10 reinstall affect my striped volume in Disk Management?

Tags: windows-10, disk-management

I setup 3 drives under a striped volume. I have to reinstall Windows 10 (seperate drive of course). If I reinstall it, will it still recognize the striped volume that was created in my current install?

Answer (score 1):

> if i reinstall it, will it still recognize the striped volume that was created in my current install?

Yes it will under the following circumstances.

- If you have RAID hardware, and you setup the striped raid there, windows cannot affect it, so neither can a reinstall.
- If you do not change the position of the SATA connectors so each harddrive remains connected the same way to your motherboard.
- If you setup a software raid in Windows Disk management, and you go to another OS that also supports this striped volume, it will be recognized during setup, and as such you can reinstall windows to the same drive (including the striped volume if you wished) or another drive.

I went from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2, where I had setup a striped partition in Windows Server 2003, and it was recognized and used on Windows Server 2008 R2. This was like 5 years ago or so, but the partitioning has not changed until today, so the same still holds.

So, From Windows 2000 and onwards, you can have software raid, and all these windows installs will correctly detect the striped partition during install and maintain its integrity.

It will not work if you go from Windows to say... linux, nor will it work if you create a linux software raid setup, then go to windows.

So, keep that in mind if you decide to later do a multi-boot setup with windows and linux side-by-side.